# why I get error 500 on ajax with GET method in laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-8

Laravel Ajax "Get" Method - Error 500

Hello,
I have maded 2 laravel project, one for testing ajax that working fine, and other one that have same ajax give error 500.

here is my controller

```
class SearchOrdersController extends Controller
{

function fetch_data(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $sort_by = $request->get('sortby');
        $sort_type = $request->get('sorttype');
        $query = $request->get('query');
        $query = str_replace(" ", "%", $query);
        
        $orders = Order::query();
        if (is_numeric($query)) {
            $orders->where('amount', '<', $query);
        } elseif (!empty($query)) {
            $currency = Currency::where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')->first();
            if (!is_null($currency)) {
                $orders->where('currency_id', $currency->id);
            }
        }
        $data = $orders->orderBy($sort_by, $sort_type)->paginate(6);
        return view('panel.user.order.pagination_data')->with(['data' => $data])->render();


    }
}
}
```

my javascript :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function fetch_data(page, sort_type, sort_by, query) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/pagination/fetch_data?page=" + page + "&sortby=" + sort_by + "&sorttype=" +
                    sort_type + "&query=" + query,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('tbody').html('');
                    $('tbody').html(data);
                }
            })
        }
}
```

and my route without any middleware :

```
Route::get('/pagination/fetch_data', 'User\SearchOrdersController@fetch_data');
```

the csrftoken for "Get" not needed!
why this code is working in another laravel project and not in this?

thanks
regards

Comment: Always the first step, when you get a 500 and the reason is not immediately apparent: You go check what the error log has to say.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved,
these errors is on Laravel.log

storage/laravel/laravel.log

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).